# i7-980X CPU on EVGA X56 showing 000

Tags: windows, cpu

My [i7-980X](http://ark.intel.com/products/47932/Intel-Core-i7-980X-Processor-Extreme-Edition-12M-Cache-3_33-GHz-6_40-GTs-Intel-QPI?q=%20i7-980X) CPU on EVGA X56 shows 000 in Windows (7 x64), CPU-Z or any other hardware identification software.

I have the Turbo Performance disabled in the BIOS just in case someone would suggest doing that.

Comment: What is the question?  Besides the error in the identification what is the problem?

Comment: @Ramhound Why isn't the processor name showing (i.e. i7-980X)?

Comment: Was this information always missing or is this behavior new?

Comment: Yes. It's been always like that.

Answer (score 0):

OK. This happens when the processor is an engineering edition, hence the version will not be recognised by installed software.

Comment: How did you even get your hands on an engineering sample? :D